# grafana variable value with label_replace

Tags: prometheus, grafana

```
label_values (
  label_replace(kube_ingress_info{namespace="$namespace"}, "ingress", "prod/$1", "ingress", "(.*)") ,
 ingress
)
```

getting errors as shown in the pic below

[image]

The following query runs OK in prometheus UI

```
label_replace(kube_ingress_info{namespace="prod"}, "ingress", "prod/$1", "ingress", "(.*)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use query_result instead of label_values like this.

```
query_result(sum by (ingress) (label_replace(kube_ingress_info{namespace="$namespace"}, "ingress", "$namespace/$1", "ingress", "(.*)")))
```

[image]

Hope this helps!
Documentation: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/#query-variable